# How to get the value of the checked boxes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a following code in html, which use checkbox align as a row

```
<tr class="reg_name">
  <th class="custom-th">Reg. Name</th>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="Y:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="N:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="B:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="I:1"></td>
</tr>
```

with a button

```
<button type="button" class="purchase__save btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
```

and this js code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.purchase__save').click(function() {
    var box_array = [];
    var boxes = $('.reg_name input[name="reg_name[]"]:checked');
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      box_array[i] = boxes.val();
    }
    console.log(box_array);
  });
});
```

will try to get the value of checked box.

The problem, if try to check two checkboxes at the same time, the value from
this `<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[0]" value="Y:1"></td>` is the only thing I get.

How to get values of other checkboxes if they are checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.purchase__save').click(function() {
    var box_array = [];
    var boxes = $('input:checkbox:checked');
    $.each(boxes, function(i,v) {
      box_array[i] = $(this).val();


    })

    console.log(box_array);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="reg_name">
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="Y:1">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="N:1">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="B:1">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="I:1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" class="purchase__save btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
```

1. Use `$(this)` to get current checkbox value

Comment: @Fil glafd to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're accessing the `val()` of a collection of elements, this means it will only retrieve the value of the first element in the set.

You could improve this code by using `map()` to build the array instead:

```
$('.purchase__save').click(function() {
    var box_array = $('.reg_name input[name="reg_name[]"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    // use the array as required here...
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6aneLqu5/19/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Just cycle every checked input with [jQuery `each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function, then append the item with [JavaScript `push`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) function.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".purchase__save").click(function() {
    var box_array = [];
    $(".reg_name input[name='reg_name[]']:checked").each(function(i, v) {
      box_array.push($(v).val());
    });
    console.log(box_array);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="reg_name">
    <th class="custom-th">Reg. Name</th>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="Y:1">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="N:1">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="B:1">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="I:1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="purchase__save btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
```

Comment: The way you code in jquery is beautiful, nice and it helps

Answer (score 1):

**Working Example**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.purchase__save').click(function() {
    var box_array = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name=reg_name]:checked").each(function(){
    box_array.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(box_array);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<tr class="reg_name">
  <th class="custom-th">Reg. Name</th>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="Y:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="N:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="B:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name" value="I:1"></td>
</tr>
<button type="button" class="purchase__save btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.purchase__save').click(function() {
    var box_array = [];
    var i = 0;
    var boxes = $('.checkedIn:checked');
    console.log(boxes);
    $(boxes).each(function(){
        box_array[i] = this.value;
      i++;
    });
    console.log(box_array);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr class="reg_name">
  <th class="custom-th">Reg. Name</th>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkedIn" name="reg_name[]" value="Y:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkedIn" name="reg_name[]" value="N:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkedIn" name="reg_name[]" value="B:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkedIn" name="reg_name[]" value="I:1"></td>
</tr>
<button type="button" class="purchase__save btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're looping over your `boxes` result, but only reading the first one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  box_array[i] = boxes.val();
}
```

In the above `boxes` is a jquery object with 0 or more items, but `boxes.val()` will just read the value of the first one.

```js
$('.purchase__save').click(function() {
    var box_array = $('.reg_name input[name="reg_name[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    
    console.log(box_array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="reg_name">
  <th class="custom-th">Reg. Name</th>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="Y:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="N:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="B:1"></td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="reg_name[]" value="I:1"></td>
</tr>
  </table>

<button type="button" class="purchase__save btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

Because you do not have id or name specified for your inputs you need to access them from different way.

```
$.('.text-center > input:checked')
```

This should do the trick. Your searching all items with class "text-center" and theirs direct input childs with checked selector

**EDIT** This will return JQuery object and notice Jamiec answer!